# Error in installing opencv3 with homebrew and python3

Tags: opencv, cmake, homebrew, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I'm using homebrew installing opencv3 on OSX(EI Captain),

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3 --HEAD
```

and an error occurred:

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Installing opencv3 from homebrew/science
==> Cloning https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
Updating /Users/ksun/Library/Caches/Homebrew/opencv3--git
==> Checking out branch master
==> Cloning https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
Updating /Users/ksun/Library/Caches/Homebrew/opencv3--contrib--git
> ==> Checking out branch master
Error: No such file or directory - /private/tmp/opencv3-20170330-14255-bxsn05/3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake
```

Can u guys help me find out how to fix it?

Answer (score 19):

I do `brew edit opencv3`, then comment the following line

```
inreplace buildpath/"3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake",
  "${OPENCV_ICV_PLATFORM}-${OPENCV_ICV_PACKAGE_HASH}",
  "${OPENCV_ICV_PLATFORM}"
```

then you can reinstall again with `--HEAD`

The opencv repository has fix some issue also removed file `3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake`, so no need to patch it any more. But they didn't issue a new release, so to install `--with-contrib`, you have to install with `--HEAD`, but disable the patch of file `3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake`

Comment: This worked for me, but FYI you've got a typo in the code block (`ippicv/ippicv.cmake` should be `ippicv/downloarder.cmake`)

Comment: what is --HEAD and why do we want it?

Comment: If --HEAD is passed, and formula defines it, install the HEAD version,
    aka master, trunk, unstable.  In this OpenCV case, it download source from github, compile and install

Comment: OK I find out about HEAD,.  --HEAD : "Rather than compiling a tagged OpenCV release (i.e., v3.0, v3.1, etc.) the --HEAD  switch instead clones down the bleeding-edge version of OpenCV from GitHub. Why would we bother doing this? Simple. We need to avoid the QTKit error that plagues macOS Sierra systems with the current tagged OpenCV 3 releases (please see the “Avoiding the QTKit/QTKit.h file not found error” section of this blog post for more information)"

Answer (score 8):

I experienced the same problem. I solved it by running `brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3`

I think what happened is that people updated the *../3rdparty/ippicv* folder in the repo such that the *downloader.cmake* file is no longer there, but they have not yet updated the brew formula.

brew install without `--HEAD` will build opencv3.2.0 which is good enough for me.

Comment: what is --HEAD  anyway ?

Comment: I learned about HEAD now.  it is a bleeding edge github version to avoid certain errors (particularly with mac os sierra QTKit)

Answer (score 4):

When I searched for the OpenCV Java issue this was the first result. I am posting my answer for anyone using the OpenCV Java to find it useful, too.

I was following this article: https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html

```
brew tap homebrew/science 
brew install opencv3 --HEAD --with-contrib --with-java
```

I tried by removing `--HEAD` from the above command and I was able to install it sucessfully.

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-java
```

as per this post: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/5498

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue in the following way:

```
$ brew edit opencv3
```

Find the following code block and comment all the 4 lines:

```
if build.with?("python3") && build.with?("python")
  # Opencv3 Does not support building both Python 2 and 3 versions
  odie "opencv3: Does not support building both Python 2 and 3 wrappers"
end
```

Finally install using the brew install command:

```
$ brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3
```

Reference: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/05/15/resolving-macos-opencv-homebrew-install-errors/